# Can find the bug in SyntaxError ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I ran in to this error and I have tried to debug it, but it seems impossible. Im working with Authorization. I'm following One month rails and I'm trapped at "Authorization: Who can? Who can't?"

I'm getting this error SyntaxError in Pins#index, which I can't conclude much form.

I would be really happy if any of you could find the bug!

Link to my github:

https://github.com/SillasPoulsen/Pinteresting

Comment: Please post the error message, together with a backtrace. Without this it is just guessing.

Comment: Sorry, http://i59.tinypic.com/24xggpl.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image clearly says the error

```
<% @pins.each do |pin| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= pin.description %></td>
    <td><%= pin.user.email if pin.user %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', pin %></td>
    <% if pin.user == current_user %>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %>
      <%= link_to 'Destroy', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    <% end %> 
  <% end %> # remove this line
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %></td>` you have missed tags